# I downloaded artifacts from Azure universal artifacts but which path it's getting downloaded

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-artifacts

I connected to Azure cloud shell and run the command as below to download an artifact.

```
az artifacts universal download \
--organization "https://abc.visualstudio.com/" \
--feed "Pkgs1" \
--name "pkg-signed" \
--version "3.1.0" \
--path .
```

It shows download progress but once completed where can I access these files?

Comment: "." would suggest your current working directory.

Comment: @RamanSailopal How to find out my current working directory?

Comment: You can find out by typing pwd

Comment: It shows as '/home/nandakumar'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the command syntax was having issues hence I made the command into single line as below

```
az artifacts universal download --organization "https://abc.visualstudio.com/" --feed "Pkgs1" --name "pkg-signed" --version "3.1.0" --path .
```

Then ran the command in Powershell command line of my local machine. After it showed success the file was downloaded into the running directory of my Powershell (It was *C:\Windows\System32*)

It runs fine in Azure CLI too. But in Azure portal not sure where it gets downloaded and how to access.

Answer (score 1):

`--path .` means the current working directory running the command. For example (I am using Windows), the following command will download the artifact to `C:\WINDOWS\system32`:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>az artifacts universal download --organization "https://dev.azure.com/org/" --feed "test1" --name "up" --version "0.0.4" --path .
```

You could specify the path using `--path` parameter. In this way, you could download the artifact to anywhere you want to. For example, the following command will download the artifact to `C:\Users\cece\Desktop\Newfolder`:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>az artifacts universal download --organization "https://dev.azure.com/org/" --feed "test1" --name "up" --version "0.0.4" --path C:\Users\cece\Desktop\Newfolder
```

Comment: Thanks. will try that and out and let you know.

Comment: No. It's not working like that. It's stored in the cloud drive. I'm not sure how to access my cloud drive on azure

Comment: Have you checked @Bhargavi Annadevara's updated reply? Does it solve your issue?

Comment: No. I am still not sure how to download from that.

Comment: I think one confusion can be that it might not be a single file downloaded, but multiple spread out over multiple directories, so its for example possible that one file goes into some pre-existing directory. To see exactly what was downloaded, create a new directory and point `--path` to that.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to [copy your files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#copy-files) in your pipeline **BEFORE** publishing your packages.

> The Universal Packages task in Azure Pipelines is set to use `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` as the default publish directory. To ready your Universal Package for publishing, move the files you wish to publish to that directory. You can also use the [Copy Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/copy-files-v2?view=azure-pipelines&tabs=yaml) utility task to copy those files to the publish directory.

Download was working fine for me and it turns out that my package was empty.

Adding this before publishing my packages did the trick:

```yaml
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    Contents: '**'
    TargetFolder: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
```

Answer (score 0):

`--path .` in the [az artifacts universal download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/artifacts/universal?view=azure-cli-latest#ext_azure_devops_az_artifacts_universal_download) command above specifies that the package contents should be placed in the current Directory.

So, on Azure Cloud Shell, you should be able to find the packages downloaded to your current working directory, i.e., the path from where you run this command. You can list them by simply running `ls`.

For example:

[image: az artifacts universal download]

**UPDATE:**

Cloud Shell utilizes Azure File storage to persist files across sessions. The file share mounts as `clouddrive` in your `$Home` directory (this is a one-time action, and the file share mounts automatically in subsequent sessions).

Now, if you want to access these files from the Azure Portal, you first have to know the File Share and Storage Account name that is being used by Cloud Shell.

To discover which file share is mounted as `clouddrive`, run the `df` command.

The file path to clouddrive shows your storage account name and file share in the URL. For example, `//storageaccountname.file.core.windows.net/filesharename`

```
bhargavi@Azure:~$ df
Filesystem                                    1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
overlay                                        50758760 15143560  35598816  30% /
tmpfs                                           2020152        0   2020152   0% /dev
tmpfs                                           2020152        0   2020152   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                                      50758760 15143560  35598816  30% /home
shm                                               65536        8     65528   1% /dev/shm
//mystorageaccount.file.core.windows.net/myfs   6291456  5242880   1048576  84% /usr/csuser/clouddrive
tmpfs                                           2020152        0   2020152   0% /sys/firmware
/dev/loop0                                      5095040   496952   4319560  11% /home/bhargavi
```

You can then navigate to your Storage Account on Azure Portal to access your files.

Comment: ls shows them. But it's stored in the cloud drive of azure. How to access and download the files?

Comment: @KBNanda Added more details to my answer above to address your query. Please check. Hope that helps.

Comment: From that url how will I download. Still I am not sure how to download that?